# usb mouse freeze on mid 2007 macbook with lion 10.7.5 installed

Tags: macos, usb, mouse

I bought a mid 2007 white MacBook used with Lion 10.7.5 installed. My usb mouse freezes after using it for about an hour plugged in. I tried both usb ports and the mouse will work for about a min. but then freezes again. Could it be a driver issue? If so where would I download the drivers?
The mouse works perfect on my W8 computer.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to try another USB mouse, perhaps a different make and model, and see if it also locks up on your Mac. If so, then it's pretty certain that your first mouse is defective or incompatible with Lion for some reason. If several mice lock up, then perhaps there is something wrong with the USB controller on the motherboard of the MacBook. But it is much more likely that the fault is with the mouse.